# How to run multiple lines of javascript on the server?

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm trying to use the following code with jade

```
extends ../display

- var mProximoAtendimento = moment(), tempoAtraso;
- if (model.ProximoAtendimento) {
-   mProximoAtendimento = moment(model.ProximoAtendimento, "YYYYMMDDHHmmss");
-   if (model.ProximoAtendimento.isValid() && moment().toDate() > model.ProximoAtendimento.toDate())
-      tempoAtraso = mDate.fromNow();
- }

block content
    .page-header
        h1= model.Nome
            |  
            small= model.Titulo

    - if (tempoAtraso)
        #{tempoAtraso}
    - else
        | #{mProximoAtendimento.fromNow()}
```

But the error is displayed:

```
500 TypeError: /var/lib/stickshift/XXXX/app-root/data/544682/views/contatos/detalhes.jade:19 17| #{tempoAtraso} 18| - else > 19| | #{mProximoAtendimento.fromNow()} Cannot call method 'fromNow' of undefined
```

Value in `model.ProximoAtendimento` is 
`2013-06-29 09:58:55`

Comment: The error tells that the `mProximoAtendimento` is undefined. Perhaps an extra m is causing the error ?

Comment: I know, I'm not understanding why, `model.ProximoAtendimento` it is set! And is a valid date!

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error when the object isn't available in the template engine.

In your main node.js file (app.js, server.js, or whichever is the root file) you need to add this for your mDate and moment objects:

```
app.locals.mDate = mDate;
app.locals.moment = moment;
```

I've found that templates render a lot faster when they don't have to do data calculations, so we've moved this sort of code into the routes wherever possible.